# Using Boolean Statements to Address a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a Pandas DF and would like to isolate specific portions of it based on some boolean conditions. The following two lines work as I want them to:

```
df['test'] = df[df.N == 30].my_variable
df['test2'] = df[df.Y >0.4].my_variable
```

Not being that familiar with Pandas yet I then tried to write:

```
df['test'] = df[df.N == 30 & df.Y >0.4].my_variable
```

But this throws the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and
>   the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types
>   according to the casting rule ''safe''

Can anyone suggest the correct (or a better) way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Not familiar with pandas, but shouldn't you be using `and` rather than `&` to do a logical "AND"?

Comment: Have you tried putting parenthesis around the individual filters? Something like : `df[(df['col1']>=1)&(df['col1']<=1)]`

Comment: Oh, this could also be an operator precedence issue, since `&` binds more tightly than `==` and `>` do, so parentheses around your conditions would also be a good thing.

Comment: In pandas .13 (just released) you can also use `df.query("N == 30 & Y > 0.4")['my_variable']`

Comment: Interestingly the error depends on the dtype of the column (and sometimes the incorrect precedence won't raise).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can wrap this with parenthesis to force the correct precedence:

```
df[(df.N == 30) & (df.Y > 0.4)].my_variable
```

It's worth mentioning that you can use `loc` (which I think is slightly cleaner):

```
df.loc[(df['N'] == 30) & (df['Y'] > 0.4), 'my_variable']
```

Comment: Yet another option is to use `DataFrame.query()`: `df.query('N == 30 and Y > 0.4').my_variable`

Comment: Just saw @TomAugspurger's comment :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud Showing off the new query method :D.... Is there a cunning way/syntax to query it so that it just extracts one column? i.e. collect my_variable inside the query?

Comment: No :) Now you're in SQL land since that's basically a `SELECT my_variable FROM df WHERE N = 30 and Y > 0.4` thing. You could always select it out first via `df[['my_variable']].query('N == 30 and Y > 0.4')`.

Comment: Hey look at that they're almost the same length :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud if you select it first you don't have access to the other columns :( ?

Comment: Oh duh...my bad ... no there's no way to do that then :/